# MJPEG Livestream causes the page to never stop loading

Tags: javascript, http-live-streaming, mjpeg

I am currently setting up a little wifi controlled car on my raspberry pi with a livestream. I am grabbing the stream from a server which runs on the pi on a different port, I am embedding the video.mjpeg file with a simple img tag. The stream works fine but the page doesnt stop loading (which makes somewhat sense of course). The problem is that now my javascript doesn't start because window.onload is not fired. Is there some simple workaround for this problem?

```
    <main>
        <img src="http://raspberrypi:8080/stream/video.mjpeg" id="stream" alt="stream" />
    </main>
```

Comment: Hi, would you pls provide some code? At first look i would say that this could be the right state that the site is loading, because of the character of a stream. A Stream is a flow of data of which you dont know where the end is ;) So the site keeps loading depending on how you have implemented the display of the stream.

Comment: When looking at the timeLine in the Safari, it appears that it doesn't event stop loading after the src of the img-Tag was set to #.  Not even removing the image tag helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use the [jquery-clipchamp-mjpeg-player-plugin](https://github.com/clipchamp/jquery-clipchamp-mjpeg-player-plugin)

Give this a try

Comment: Darn, when using the clipchamp player, there are issues with CORS again.. What's wrong with MJPG so that modern browsers have such a hard time properly supporting it?

Comment: Unfortuanlty the plugin hasn't aged well and is archieved / no longer working.